# How can I remove an object from an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to remove an object from an array. Here is the schema I'm working with:

```
event: {
    invitees: {
        users : [{
            user: {
                type: String,
                ref: 'User'
            },
        }],
    }
}
```

The query I'm using is listed below, but it isn't working. Basically, nothing happens when I run this script.

```
Event.update(
        {"_id": req.params.event_id},
        {"$pull": {"invitees.users.user": req.params.user_id}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true},
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            return res.json({ success: true });
        }
    );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `field` of the [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) operator identifies the array to pull the elements from that match its `query`.

So your update should look like this instead:

```js
Event.update(
    {"_id": req.params.event_id},
    // { $pull: { <array field>: <query> } }
    {"$pull": {"invitees.users": {"user": req.params.user_id}}},
    {safe: true, upsert: true},
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        return res.json({ success: true });
    }
);
```